# typeerror: character buffer expected

Tags: integer, buffer, typeerror

below is a section of my code where i am trying to output a string and an integer to a file.  It would not let me output more than on thing at a time so I had to put them on seperate lines.  I also now have an error saying:

```
TypeError: Expected a character buffer object
```

referring to the line outputting the variable count.
 Can someone tell me how to fix this error? Also if I could somehow combine all this into one line that would be cool too. Thanks!

```
print outfile.write ("(" + currentuser + ")")
print outfile.write (" ")
print outfile.write (count)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.write()` method of file objects takes a string argument. To write an integer, you need to convert it to a string first.

```
outfile.write("(%s) %s" % (currentuser, count))
```

is probably what you're looking for. I'm not sure why you're `print`ing the return values, since `.write()` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

If this is Python (which I am not sure about), try

```
print outfile.write ("(" + currentuser + ") " + str(count))
```

or

```
print outfile.write("(%s) %d" % (currentuser, count))
```

or

```
print outfile.write("({0}) {1}".format(currentuser, count))
```